# How to call IE11 specific css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing padding problem in IE11 and i tried to control css using IE specific statements like

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:kin/frontend/enterprise/wyf-upgrade/css/styles-ie-11.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

but this condition not worked properly. kindly please suggest any solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: IE 10+ do not support condcom.

Comment: What is the padding problem? Maybe you could solve it there without having to use something different specifically for IE11.

Comment: Is it just IE11 you want to target or is IE9+ also good?

Comment: http:kin/frontend/enterprise/wyf-upgrade/css/styles-ie-11.css is this address correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works for me

```
$(window).load(function() {
      if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv:11\./)) {
          $('body').addClass('ie11');
     }

});

body.ie11 #some-other-div{
}
```

[check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WNPR/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 11) {
  $("body").addClass("ie11");
}
```

This example check if the browser is IE11, if true, it adds the class 'ie11' to the body element so you can specify style in your stylesheet which should only be applied on IE11.

Comment: `$.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9.